# How add if statement to create in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel.

This is part of my code:

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            $typeProceeding = $this->typeProceeding->where('id', $term->type_proceeding_id)->first()->name;


            $calendar->event(Event::create($term->name)
                ->name($term->name)
                ->description($term->description)
                ->uniqueIdentifier($user->id . '-' . $term->id)
                ->createdAt(new DateTime($term->created_at))
                ->startsAt(new DateTime($term->begin_date))
                ->endsAt(new DateTime($term->end_date))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('CLASS', 'PUBLIC'))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('CREATED', $term->created_at))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('LAST-MODIFIED', $term->updated_at))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('SEQUENCE', $key))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('TRANSP', 'OPAQUE'))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('LOCATION', ''))



                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('STATUS', strtoupper($this->termStatus->where('id', $term->term_status_id)->first()->name)))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('TYPE-PROCEEDING', strtoupper($typeProceeding)))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-ATTENDANCE', ($term->regards_attendance == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-CORRESPONDENCE', ($term->regards_correspondence == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'))

            );
        };
```

It's work fine but I need add something like this:

```
if(asset($term->term_status_id) { 
->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('STATUS', strtoupper($this->termStatus->where('id', $term->term_status_id)->first()->name)))
}

if(asset($term->regards_attendance){
->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-ATTENDANCE', ($term->regards_attendance == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'))
}
```

My object not always has term_status_id and regards_attendance.

How can I make it?

Please help me

Comment: To get started, what are you trying to accomplish? In order to provide you a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**property_exists — Checks if the object or class has a property**

```
  if(property_exists($term,'term_status_id') { 
    ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('STATUS', strtoupper($this- 
     >termStatus->where('id', $term->term_status_id)->first()->name)))
    }



  if(property_exists($term,'regards_attendance'){
    ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-ATTENDANCE', ($term- 
     >regards_attendance == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'))
    }
```

Comment: Where I must add it? After  $calendar->event(Event::create($term->name) ?

Comment: Can you show me full code (yours code with my code)?

Comment: I think you can add it at the top of  $calendar->event(Event:: create($term->name)  and then store the query result in some variable the use that varible inside appendProperty()

Comment: If I make this: https://pastebin.com/dRHCC4d6 I have php error syntax :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            $typeProceeding = $this->typeProceeding->where('id', $term->type_proceeding_id)->first()->name;
            $event = Event::create($term->name)
                ->name($term->name)
                ->description($term->description)
                ->uniqueIdentifier($user->id . '-' . $term->id)
                ->createdAt(new DateTime($term->created_at))
                ->startsAt(new DateTime($term->begin_date))
                ->endsAt(new DateTime($term->end_date))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('CLASS', 'PUBLIC'))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('CREATED', $term->created_at))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('LAST-MODIFIED', $term->updated_at))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('SEQUENCE', $key))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('TRANSP', 'OPAQUE'))
                ->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('LOCATION', ''));
            
            if(!empty($term->term_status_id)){
                $event = $event->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('STATUS', strtoupper($this->termStatus->where('id', $term->term_status_id)->first()->name)));
            }
            if(!empty($term->regards_attendance)){
                $event = $event->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-ATTENDANCE', ($term->regards_attendance == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'));
            }
            $event = $event->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('TYPE-PROCEEDING', strtoupper($typeProceeding)))->appendProperty(TextPropertyType::create('REGARDS-CORRESPONDENCE', ($term->regards_correspondence == 0) ? 'NIE' : 'TAK'));

            $calendar->event($event);
        };
```

Comment: this return error: Argument 1 passed to Spatie\IcalendarGenerator\Components\Component::appendProperty() must be an instance of Spatie\IcalendarGenerator\PropertyTypes\PropertyType, string given, called in /var/www/app/Services/iCal/iCalService.php on line 52